# Discovering variable ranges, parsing/summing data in those ranges

Tags: variables, excel-formula, string-parsing, range

```
  |        A         |  B   |    C       |   D   |   E   |   F   |  G    |
  +------------------+------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  |                  |      | Allocation | Alloc | Alloc | Alloc | Alloc |
1 | Name/Class       | FTE  |        All |   ADM |   ECE |    HS |    LS |
  +==================+======+============+=======+=======+=======+=======+
2 | Smith, James     | 0.88 |       100% |  100% |    0% |    0% |    0% |
3 |   ADM: Class 230 | 0.88 |       100% |       |       |       |       |
4 | Doe, Jill        | 1.00 |       100% |    0% |  100% |    0% |    0% |
5 |   ECE: Class 112 | 1.00 |       100% |       |       |       |       |
6 | Marx, Karl       | 0.85 |       100% |    0% |    0% |   24% |   76% |
7 |   HS: Class 004  | 0.10 |        12% |       |       |       |       |
8 |   HS: Class 018  | 0.10 |        12% |       |       |       |       |
9 |   LS: Class 230  | 0.30 |        35% |       |       |       |       |
10|   LS: Class 235  | 0.35 |        41% |       |       |       |       |
11| Bush, George     | 0.50 |       100% |    0% |   40% |   40% |   20% |
12|   ECE: Class 120 | 0.15 |        30% |       |       |       |       |
13|   ECE: Class 123 | 0.05 |        10% |       |       |       |       |
14|   HS: Class 670  | 0.20 |        40% |       |       |       |       |
15|   LS: Class 580  | 0.10 |        20% |       |       |       |       |
16| TBH, FacultyHS   | 0.29 |       100% |    0% |    0% |  100% |    0% |
17|   HS: Class 912  | 0.29 |       100% |       |       |       |       |
18| Tell, William    | 1.00 |       100% |     … |     … |     … |     … |
19|   [etc]
```

I need help with a formula for cols C through G...

I have a table of seven columns, where cols A & B are hard data, and C:G need to be calculated.

Col A has a listing of names and classes. The pattern is Name followed by a variable number of classes. The only way to reliably determine if the value is a name or a class is the presence of a colon (:).

There are four class types, ADM, ECE, HS and LS. Under each name, there can be any number of a given class type, and any combination of the four class types. For example, under a given Name, there might be three 'HS' class types, and one 'ECE' class type, etc.

Column B contains a number value. If the row is a name, the number value is a sum of the class(es) immediately below it.

I need to create a column C, D, E, F, G as follows:

- Col C ('Allocation All'): If the row is a name, then allocation is 100%. If the row is a class, then the allocation is the percentage of that class FTE (col B) to the FTE total for the parent name (col B);
- Col D ('Allocation ADM'): If the row is a Name, then this cell is the percentage of the sum of all 'ADM:...' classes immediately below this Name;
- Col D ('Allocation ADM'): If the row is a Class, the cell is blank;
- Col E ('Allocation ECE'): Same as Col D, except for 'ECE:...' classes;
- Col F ('Allocation HS'): Same as Col D, except for 'HS:...' classes;
- Col G ('Allocation LS'): Same as Col D, except for 'LS:...' classes

For example, note that D2 (ADM) = C3, and F6 (HS) = C7+C8, etc.

For any given Name row, cols D:G will always total 100%.

Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this by extracting from col a all the raw data in separate columns.

You could put for example column h containing adm amounts , col I containing EEC amounts ... You could populate these colums be extracting from the raw amounts using formulas that are a combination of find and mid functions.

Once the data is laid out in this way formulas using condional logic should give you what you want.

Ps you can identify names by using find and searching for ","

Comment: I inserted two more columns for 'Cost Center' and 'Class Count'. Those were easy to populate, and from there, I was able to extract the data as you suggested and come up with the percentages I needed. Thanks!